# How to print the number of keys with the values greater than 0.1 in at least one sample (in each group)?

Tags: r, tidyverse

How to print the number of keys with the values greater than 0.1 in at least one sample (in each group).
I am using these commands to separate each group and calculate the number of keys that satisfy the
above condition. How can I do this using group_by(Group) function from tidyverse at once?

```
input <- tribble(
~Key, ~Group, ~sample1, ~sample2, ~sample3, ~samplen,
"a1", "ABC", 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0,
"a2", "ABC", 1, 2, 3, 0,
"a3", "DEF", 0, 0, 0, 0,
"a4", "DEF", 2, 22, 23, 2,
"a5", "DEF", 0, 0, 0.1, 0
)

ABC <- input %>% 
  filter(Group=="ABC")
dat<-ABC[,-c(1:1)]
aux<-apply(dat,2,function(x){x>=0.1})
sel.gene<-apply(aux,2,sum)
sel.gene.1<-which(sel.gene>=1)
ABC_output <-dat[,sel.gene.1]
dim(ABC_output)

DEF <- input %>% 
  filter(Group=="DEF")
dat<-DEF[,-c(1:1)]
aux<-apply(dat,2,function(x){x>=0.1})
sel.gene<-apply(aux,2,sum)
sel.gene.1<-which(sel.gene>=1)
DEF_output <-dat[,sel.gene.1]
dim(DEF_output)
```

Desired_output

```
ABC  2
DEF  1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to `filter` the data frame first with `filter_at` (*sample* columns) + `any_vars`, then `count` *Group*:

```r
input %>% 
    filter_at(vars(starts_with('sample')), any_vars(. > 0.1)) %>% 
    count(Group)

# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  Group     n
#  <chr> <int>
#1   ABC     2
#2   DEF     1
```

Another option: create a condition column, then summarize by *Group*:

```r
input %>% 
    mutate(n = rowSums(select(., starts_with('sample')) > 0.1) > 0) %>% 
    group_by(Group) %>% 
    summarise(n = sum(n))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  Group     n
#  <chr> <int>
#1   ABC     2
#2   DEF     1
```

Comment: Thank you very much. How can I count samples per group instead of keys ( If a sample has more than 0.1 in a group. )

Comment: I am not at the desk to answer your question. But you can modify the second option by removing the > 0 part

Comment: ok noworries. Remove >0 gvies `ABC 4 and DEF 4` but it should be `ABC 3, DEF 4`.  In this case it should be `colSums` no?

Comment: Removing `> 0` gives the total count of values in sample columns that are larger than 0.1. So it seems you need to count how many sample contains at least one value larger than 0.1, in which case, you can leverage `summarize_at`. Something like `input %>% group_by(Group) %>% summarise_at(vars(starts_with('sample')), funs(any(. > 0.1))) %>% transmute(Group, n = rowSums(select(., starts_with('sample'))))`

Comment: This is working perfectly. Thank you very much. However, I noticed it is very slow on matrix with 50k cols and 1k rows.